# How to use variable content to read content of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFE2Z.jpg)

this._formService.arraySteps[j].profile[i].nom = newValue;

where `i` and `j` are indexes

How can I make this works using variable instead of text.

I've tried the following where

```
tmpKeyName = "profile"
keyObject = "nom"

this._formService.arraySteps[j][tmpKeyName][i][keyObject];
```

Thanks

Comment: looks fine to me... do you have any errors showing up?

Comment: Please give us the object structure then it'll help others to help you

Comment: You tried that and then what not happened..?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your array/object structure is correct, your code would work:

```js
// let's assume that this._formService.arraySteps was the following array of objects:
var arraySteps = [
  {
    profile: [
      {nom: "something"}
    ]
  },
  {
    profile: [
      {nom: "something else"}
    ]
  },
  {
    profile:[
      {nom: "something totally different"}
    ]
  }
];

var tmpKeyName = "profile";
var keyObject = "nom";

// Looping through that array:
for(var j = 0; j < arraySteps.length; ++j){
  
  // Looping through the objects in the array:
  for(var i = 0; i < arraySteps[j][tmpKeyName].length; ++i){
   console.log(arraySteps[j][tmpKeyName][i][keyObject]);
  }
}
```